# How to put another website in my app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe, webview, electron

I want to put another website in my app for both desktop and mobile, and add some additional button.

[image: Like the picture.]

I can use `<webview>` tag in Electron. But i can't find a good solution in Cordova.

My expect behavior is convert the always keep in one window. And in Electron I listen the `new-window` event, then open in current window.

```
this.webview.nativeElement.addEventListener('new-window', (e: any) => {
    this.webview.nativeElement.loadURL(e.url)
});
```

I have tried `<iframe>`, but some website has a limit for iframe. And I can't disable the new window function (like `target=_blank`).

Hope someone can give me some idea for cordova platform.

Comment: If you cannot use iFrame and since your buttons cannot interact with an iframe from a different domain, your best bet is a server proxy that grabs the other site and adds your buttons.